# Change value of a hidden textfield using jquery to a value from php

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I have a plugin implemented in php that has an array of values. The code looks like this:

```
class AutoChangeCustomer extends Plugin
{
  public $warehouseUserToCustomer = ['3' => '65059' , '4' => '1'];

  public function getName(){
    return __CLASS__;
  }

  public function install()
  {
    parent::install();
  }
}
```

And I have a textfield in HTML defined as

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="{$smarty.const._SHIPPING_STORE_CUSTOMER_ID}" />
```

I want to check if the plugin is installed then the value of the textfield should be changed to a value stored in my array $warehouseUserToCustomer defined in the plugin and I implemented a jQuery function that changes the value of the hidden field like this:

```
 function setCustomerID()
 {
   $("#customer_id").val(warehouseUserToCustomer(0))
 }
```

But it doesn't work because I don't know how to check if a plugin is installed, does anyone know how to perform the check and then pass the parameter to the jQuery function?

Comment: There is some issue there. You can only pass data from JS to PHP using ajax or http get/post... Else there is no communication between them.

Comment: I want to pass data from PHP to JS, to change the value of the textfield to a parameter from the array in the plugin

Comment: Which plugin is it? Just check by a conditional if you can create an object from this plugin and then assign the value to the html.

Comment: Yes, this if statement works          {if $AutoChangeCustomerOnCashRegisterOrder == 1}
            <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="{$warehouseUserToCustomer}" />
        {/if}

Comment: But how do I assign the value of the array to the textfield?

Comment: Does something like `<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="<php echo $customer_id; ?>" />` work? Where `$customer_id` is a PHP variable?

Comment: You need to use the class to access the element using $object->function.